# pass delegating object type as protocol method argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I want to pass my delegating object as an argument with a declared type so I don't have to cast (if I pass (id)sender instead):

```
@protocol myObjectDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myObjectAsArgument:(myObject *)object;
@end

@interface myObject : NSObject
    // stuff...
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id <myObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

What would be the correct way of doing this? Like I said, I know I could do this:

```
- (void)myObjectAsArgument:(id)object;
```

And that would let me pass `self` in as argument, but I don't like using the cast syntax.

Thanks.

NOTE:

Apple does that too:

```
@protocol UITableViewDataSource <NSObject>
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
@end

@interface UITableView : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@end
```

That's just one method from the UITableViewDataSource protocol and it's passing a UITableView type as argument.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is top Google search result, here's how to do it:

```
@class myObject;  // just need this for compiling

@protocol myObjectDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myObjectAsArgument:(myObject *)object;
@end

@interface myObject : NSObject
    // stuff...
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <myObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: I don't think which is a good idea where to keep a strong reference on a delegate.

Comment: delegate references should always be strong, it's in Apple's docs

Comment: just because you CAN, doesn't mean you should, and in this case there's nothing to say you can't do either.  basically what if I want to keep my object in memory until my delegate owner AND my delegating object are sent for garbage collection?  why not?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
- (void)myObjectAsArgument:(id<myObjectDelegate>)object;
```

with `myObjectDelegate` being the name of your protocol ;)

Comment: hey, that would be passing the delegate object as argument, I added one line in my interface declaration for you.

Comment: essentially, it's the delegat-ING object that I want to pass

Comment: well. I didn't know that people would actually like to do that :D I think the only way to do what you are doing is either hardcode your type into your protocol, use subclassing or create a second protocol

Comment: Well...  you should have told us, that your problem was that the type wasnt recognized. Your question sounded like you want to have a generic case. Depending where you declare your protocol you dont need the @class